# Grouping Sql Tables

Tags: sql-server-2008, group-by

I have three tables which i have joined ..but the manner in which i have to display them is a little difficult for me to understand.I am trying to group them and not getting the desired result.

```
Sports_Name

Id |  Name
---------
1     Football
2     Cricket
3     Hockey   
4     Tenis


Teams

Id  |  Sport_Id | Team_Name
----------------------------
101      1         Manchester United
103      2         Australia
104      2         India
109      1         Real Madrid
110      3         New Zeland


Player_Name

Id  |  Team_Id |  Player_Name
------------------------------
1       101         Rooney
2       104         Tendulkar
3       103         Ponting
4       109         Ronaldo
5       101         Van Persie
6       110         Simond
```

I need to display this information in the following manner..

```
**Football**    
Manchester United -Rooney
Manchester United -Van Persie
Real Madrid -Ronaldo

**Cricket**
India-Tendulkar
Australia-Ponting

**Hockey**
New Zeland -Simond

and something similar for tenis
```

See this picture for details

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT sports_name.name, teams.team_name, player_name.player_name  FROM player_name
JOIN 
  teams ON
player_name.team_ID = teams.ID
JOIN 
  sports_name on
sports_name.id = teams.sport_id
order by sports_name.name, team_name
```

This gets all the data in order then you just need to use your presentation layer to use sports.name as  group header.

This produces

name    team_name   player_name
Cricket Australia   Ponting
Cricket india   Tendulkar
Football    Man u   Rooney
Football    Man u   RVP
Football    Real Madrid Ronaldo
Hockey  N Z Simond

Comment: I need to place it on a grid ..Like Foodball and the team and the player beneath..wish i could post a image but i need to earn some 10 points ..what crap !

Comment: you could just post a link to a image sharing website - in the comments.

Comment: Ok so what you are asking for is an application feature. It is using the sport name field to group by. There is no way to do this in SQL alone. The rows must be of the same type. So you couldn't have a singe tuple of SPORT then a tuple with TEAM and PLAYER in the same data set. The SQL I have provided will work fine for you in most reporting /gird software - where you just group on SPORT.

Comment: If you did really want what you've asked for then you would combine several SELECTS. e.g. SELECT 'FOOTBALL' GO SELECT sports_name.name, teams.team_name, player_name.player_name  FROM player_name
JOIN 
  teams ON
player_name.team_ID = teams.ID
JOIN 
  sports_name on
sports_name.id = teams.sport_id
order by sports_name.name, team_name GO

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT  T.TEAM_NAME+' - '+ P.PLAYER_NAME as 'FOOTBALL'
FROM    TEAMS T JOIN PLAYER_NAME P
ON      T.ID=P.TEAM_ID
JOIN    SPORTS_NAME S
ON      T.SPORT_ID=S.ID
WHERE   S.NAME='FOOTBALL'
```

Change the where clause to 'Cricket','Hockey' to get other results

Answer (score 0):

The basic query would be something like:

```
SELECT      s.Name, t.Name, p.Player_Name
FROM        Player_Name     p
INNER JOIN  Teams       t
ON      t.Id = p.Team_id
INNER JOIN  Sports_Name s
ON      s.Id = t.Sport_Id
```

Then if you want to display the results like you described it, my guess would be to use [a cursor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/ms180169.aspx). Use [parameterized procedure](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v8/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.udb.doc/ad/c0011919.htm) to add a `WHERE` clause to the query in order to filter the results by sport's name.